# Receiving to array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Hello I'm trying to get parameters to my array of structs but when I try to use "scanf" It gives me an error

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

I would be happy if you help me understand what It results from and how I can fix it.
 Thank you

My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 6

struct player
{
char name[20]; 
float height;
float points_number; 
int vest_number; 
};

int main()
{
struct player basketball;
int i,j;

for(i = 0; i < N ; i++)
{
    for(j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
    {
        printf("Enter player name: \n");
        scanf("%s",basketball[i].name[j]);
    }
    printf("Enter Player height: \n");
    scanf("%f",&basketball[i].height);
    printf("Enter average number of points: \n");
    scanf("%f",&basketball[i].points_number);
    printf("Enter vest number: \n");
    scanf("%d",&basketball[i].vest_number);
}

 }
```

Comment: Does this look like an **array** : `struct player basketball;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare only 1 `struct player basketball;` but you try to use 6. This is not good. And `char name[20]` does not mean you have 20 strings, but you have 1 with a maximum of 20 characters.

You should either allocate dynamically the memory for the players or use arrays.

And when you use `scanf` you need to pass in the **address** of the data you are trying to read into.

Comment: So how do you recommend me to create N arrays(6) each with the struct parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

To define an array of struct player:

```
player basketball[6];
```

To read each player data:

```
for(i = 0; i < N ; i++)
{
    printf("Enter player name: \n");
    scanf("%s",&basketball[i].name);
    printf("Enter Player height: \n");
    scanf("%f",&basketball[i].height);
    printf("Enter average number of points: \n");
    scanf("%f",&basketball[i].points_number);
    printf("Enter vest number: \n");
    scanf("%d",&basketball[i].vest_number);
}
```